# Expected number of correct answers in a "bijection exercise"

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, matching-theory

Say you have a language exercise where you have to match $n>2$ words with $n$ images. If you draw $n$ edges uniformly at random step by step (first edge, starting from vertex $1$ goes to image $l_1\in\{1,\dots,n\} $ w.p. $1/n$, second edge starting at vertex $2$ goes to $l_2\in\{1,\dots,n\}\backslash \{l_1\}$ w.p. ${1\over n-1}$ etc), forming a random perfect matching after $n$ time steps, what is the expected number of correct edges?

Let $k_i$ be the number of matchings on $n-i+n-i$ vertices such that no edge is correct. (From the hat check problem).

So $P[\text{exactly }i\text{ correct edges}] = {n\choose i}\cdot {1\over n}\cdots{1\over n-i+1}\cdot k_i\cdot {1\over n-i }\cdots{1\over 2}$

And from this we can compute the expectation. Does this seem correct?

Comment: It is much more handsome to leave the distribution out and go directly for the expectation by means of linearity of expectation (and symmetry). Let $X_i=1$ if vertex $i$ gives a correct edge and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then find $\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Comment: As for the actual distribution itself...  The correct expression will be $\Pr(\text{exactly }i\text{ correct edges}) = \dfrac{\binom{n}{i}\cdot !(n-i)}{n!}$ where $!k$ denotes the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on $k$ elements.  As alluded to already however, it is not recommended to approach this way as linearity of expectation is far cleaner an approach.

Comment: In other words, the probability you gave is correct, even though it's not the best way to solve the problem.